# can't connect mongodb to node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have just started learning about MongoDB and I am trying to host my Node.js application locally via MongoDB Server 6.0 (without using Mongoose or Atlas).

I copied the async JavaScript code given in the MongoDB documentation. I made sure to run mongod before executing the code app.js

this is when i run mongod

[image: this is when i run mongod]

and then when i run node app.js in my terminal nothing is being shown in my terminal.

this is my app.js code

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'fruitsDB';

// Create a new MongoClient
const client = new MongoClient(url);

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
client.connect(function(err) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  const db = client.db(dbName);
  
  // Call the function to insert documents after connecting
  insertDocuments(db, function() {
    // Close the client after finishing database operations
    client.close();
  });
});

const insertDocuments = function(db, callback) {
  // Get the documents collection
  const collection = db.collection('fruits');
  // Insert some documents
  collection.insertMany([
    {a : 1},
    {a : 2},
    {a : 3}
  ], function(err, result) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    assert.equal(3, result.result.n);
    assert.equal(3, result.ops.length);
    console.log("Inserted 3 documents into the collection");
    callback(result);
  });
}
```

and this is what's happening when i run node app.js:

[image: node app.js]

it is not getting connected

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoClient.connect is not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75373419/mongoclient-connect-is-not-responding)

Comment: If you're following a tutorial, it is seriously out-of-date

Answer (score 0):

The error looks confusing. I guess the code is outdated. Try this way -

```
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require("mongodb");

const uri = `your uri`;
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1,
});

// function to connect to the database
async function run() {
  try {
    await client.connect();               
    const dbName = client.db("fruitsDB")
    console.log("connected to database");
  }
  finally {}
}

// calling run fuction and logging any possilbe error
run().catch(console.dir);
```

Here we are doing `cient.connect()` in a async way inside the async `run()` function. Which gives more flexibility.

As you are just learning don't do the `client.close()` it can create issues sometimes.

You can go here for more details about how to connect,
[Documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/quick-start/connect-to-mongodb/)